# How can i get UIImage from "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL" without ALAssetsLibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{

    NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
    NSLog(@"url : %@",url);
}
```

I know we always use ALAssetsLibrary to get UIIMage by UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL. But it is deprecated ,so do i have other way?

By the way,the code's output below :

```
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=106E99A1-4F6A-45A2-B320-B0AD4A8E8473&ext=JPG
```

I checked apple official document,found out that ALAssetsLibrary replaced by PHPhotoLibrary .

My God ! Finally i find out ,here's the answer:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{

    NSURL *url = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[url] options:nil];
    PHAsset *asset = result.firstObject;
    PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
    [manager requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100) contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable result, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
    }];
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but do not use the string value `@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"`. Use the provided constant of `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL`.

Comment: it make no difference , do you know how to get UIImage from this url ?

Comment: Why don't just use the `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` to get the image from `info`?

Comment: I want to store a string in my Model rather than a UIImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ALAssetsLibrary is deprecated in ios9. Use [Photos Framework Reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014408)

Comment: the data will be nil , i have tried it

Comment: I have edited my answer please have a look

Comment: Yes! that's the new Framework , but which function can get a UIImage by UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL

Comment: Great happy coding